# How can I load the spData-package?

Tags: r

I want to load in the map data, which is found in `spData`.

1. I tried to install the package:

```r
    install.packages("spData")
```

2. Then I tried to load the package:

```r
    library(spData)
```

When I do this I get the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘spData’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘terra’ 1.4-22 is being loaded, but >= 1.5.12 is required

How do I solve this?

Comment: Hi @Simen Fjælberg, Welcome to SO! Reading the error message you get, it seems you need to update the `terra` library. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you have a version or `raster` that is ahead of the version of `terra` that it requires, caused by a temporary glitch at CRAN with the binary versions for Windows. The easiest way around this problem is to install the development version of `terra`, and then reinstall `raster`:

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
install.packages('raster')
```