# R packages "raster" fail to upload while searching for "terra" last version

Tags: r, package, raster, terra

I'm working in Windows 10 with R 4.1.2 in RStudio 2021.09.2. I'm working with spatial data, both vectors and rasters, but three days ago the command library(raster) started to gave me this warning:

> Error:  package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘terra’ 1.4-22 loaded, but >= 1.5.12 is required

- I tried to update terra, the update finished successfully but the
  version remains 1.4-22.
- I tried also to remove the packages (terra, raster, sf), then install
  again everything, but the error remains.
- Finally, I tried the following:

```
require(devtools)
install_version("terra", version = "1.5-12", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/terra/terra_1.5-12.tar.gz")
```

but in the end the version is the same, 1.4-22. I tried again:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/terra/terra_1.5-12.tar.gz"

install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

And nothing changed, unfortunately.
Is anyone experimenting something similar? How could I fix this error, in your opinion?
There are a lot of packages based on terra and I got stuck because seems that none of them can work without this update.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')` to install the development version on Windows.

Comment: It sounds as though you are mixing CRAN versions of packages with devel versions.  Unless you really need the devel version, you should stick with CRAN.  If you do need devel versions, you'll need to work hard to make sure everything is compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. Anyway, it didn't work:

Comment: package ‘terra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘terra’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\Alice\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK\terra\libs\x64\terra.dll to C:\Users\Alice\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\terra\libs\x64\terra.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘terra’

Comment: The "cannot remove prior installation" error is sometimes a permissions issue, but in your case I think the problem is that some of the files are likely in use.  Try this: exit all copies of R that are running on your system.  Start a clean new session, and run `remove.packages("terra")`.  Then try to install it again.

Comment: One other issue:  the Windows binary build of `terra` is still only 1.4-22.  In the short term, you'll need to build from source to get the latest release 1.5-17.  If you can't do that, you should probably go back to an earlier version of `raster` for a few days.  I think `raster` v 3.5-11 should be okay with `terra` 1.4-22.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70916632/how-can-i-load-the-spdata-package#comment125367509_70916632

Comment: Thank you to all the kind persons who tried to answer.
I finally fixed the problem by:
-restarting R in a clean new session
-removing terra package
-quitting R, then restarting again
-installing the package terra asking for the development version (https://rspatial.r-universe.dev).

Answer (score 3):

Thank you to all the kind persons who tried to answer.

I finally fixed the problem by:

- restarting R in a clean new session
- removing terra package
- quitting R, then restarting again
- installing the package terra asking for the development version:

  install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve doing the following steps:

1. Download and install RTools: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html
2. Open RStudio and run `install.packages("terra")`.
3. Confirm that you want to install it from source.
4. Wait while console compile the terra package.

Done! You can now load the raster package.

Comment: Thank you @Gorgens, I fixed by removing the package and installing the development version, since even Rtools didn't solve the problem

Comment: Yes, this is what you should do. The windows binary on CRAN just isn't updated to the newest version yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to update terra directly through R Studio interface, on the "Packages" tab? I was facing the same issue but managed to fix it by doing so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, but yes I had tried previously but it didn't work, I had to remove the package and install the development version. Please have a look at my answer for further references.