# R packages "terra" and "raster" make R crash when charging library

Tags: r, package, raster, terra

I first had the same issue than this post : [R packages "raster" fail to upload while searching for "terra" last version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70925962/18140798)
(problem with terra updating) but now, with the solutions I've got there I face a new problem :

When I charge the library of terra and so raster (and so lidR) my R crash without any explanation.

terra version: 1.5.17 (caught with install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')

raster version : 3.5-15

I'm on Win 10, fresh and reinstalled R 4.1.2, R studio and R tools. I've deleted all files during the multiple reinstallation process i've made.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with raster. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

These problems are typically caused by loading an old session, or a package that depends on the package you want to install. It is best to try to fix this by using in R-gui or command-line R; and avoid R-Studio.

Before you do anything else, run `unlink(".Rdata")` and close R answer "no" to the question "save workspace image" (I think it is a design flaw to even ask that question). And then first install terra, followed by raster.

But if you must use R-Studio, first **close all files** in R-studio, run `unlink(".Rdata")`, exit R-Studio and open it again so that you start with a clean environment. Check `sessionInfo()` to make sure than only a few base packages are loaded. And `ls()` to make sure that there are no R objects in memory.

There should be no need for R-tools as you can install the package from CRAN (`install.packages("terra")`, or, for the development versions, from the R-universe `(install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did all of this but it continue to crash anyway even with just R GUI. For the moment I'll try to work with Docker and their images of the "geospatial" packages who seems to work.