# Problem with raster and terra package in lidR

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, terra

After installing the lidR package in R, when loading it I get an error loading the required raster and terra packages. I have tried reinstalling the raster package and updating the terra package but I still get the same error. R does not recongise any functions in the lidR package because of this.

```
> library(lidR)
Loading required package: raster
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘terra’ 1.4-22 is already loaded, but >= 1.5.12 is required
Error: package ‘raster’ could not be loaded
```

It is not a problem with the lidR package but with raster and terra.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi isabelle3301, Welcome to SO! Reading the error message you get, it seems you need to update the terra library. @Robert Hijmans already gave an answer to this question yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70916632/how-can-i-load-the-spdata-package#comment125367509_70916632). Cheers.

Comment: Hi @lovalery, thank you for your help! Problem is solved :)

Comment: Glad that I could help. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers.